# What exactly is the second parameter that the fetch API takes?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I went to MDN and read about the `fetch` API and it says:

> You can also optionally pass in an init options object as the second argument

Suppose, we have this simple login function:

```js
const login = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    }

    return fetch(`apiUrl/users/authenticate`, requestOptions)
        .then(res = res.json)
            .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

So, `requestOptions` is an `init` object here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Init` object is the options with which you can initialize the fetch methods. 
The below are the most commonly used options that you can pass to `fetch` as in `init` object.

```
  1. method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  2. mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
  3. cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
  4. credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
  5. headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  7. redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
  8. referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
  9. body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
```

You can read more bout this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the "`init`" object. It's not a very descriptive name, unfortunately, but that's what the [official specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) calls it. You can see the properties it accepts [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) or in [the specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit):

```
dictionary RequestInit {
  ByteString method;
  HeadersInit headers;
  BodyInit? body;
  USVString referrer;
  ReferrerPolicy referrerPolicy;
  RequestMode mode;
  RequestCredentials credentials;
  RequestCache cache;
  RequestRedirect redirect;
  DOMString integrity;
  boolean keepalive;
  AbortSignal? signal;
  any window; // can only be set to null
};
```

(the notation is a bit odd if you're not familiar with it - the part on the left is the *type* of the value, and the part on the right is the *name* of the property)